# Save additional data to Django database

Tags: django, django-channels

I am using Django Channels and I want to be able to save additional fields to the database along with the `json` data of the post.

I have a foreign key in my `Postmie` model that points to `email` field in my user model. `Postmie` is the model responsible for saving posts to the database. The Foreign key creates a field called `email_id`. While I am saving posts to the database I want to also grab the email of the user making the post and save it in the database as well. How can I go about doing this? I am not using Django forms.

My `Postmie` model is the same as the one in the Django Channels tutorial `Post` found [here](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/blob/master/liveblog/posts/models.py), the only difference is that my model has an extra foreign key pointing to the email field in my user model.

`email=request.user.email` does not work. I was thinking about putting the email in a hidden field, but that does not seem safe to me.

The method I am using is practically the same method in the Django Channels tutorial found [here](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/blob/master/liveblog/posts/consumers.py) `consumers.py`. Everything works but I am not able to enter other fields in the database for posts.

```
def save_post(message, slug, request):
    """
    Saves vew post to the database.
    """
    post = json.loads(message['text'])['post']
    email = request.user.email
    feed = Feed.objects.get(slug=slug)
    Postmie.objects.create(feed=feed, body=post email_id=email)
```

Postmie model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Postmie(models.Model):
    # Link back to the main blog.
    feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed, related_name="postmie")
    email = models.ForeignKey(Usermie,
                              to_field="email",
                              related_name="postmie_email",  max_length=50)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    classs = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    subclass = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "#%i: %s" % (self.id, self.body_intro())

    def post_email(self):
        return self.email

    def post_subject(self):
        return self.subject

    def post_datetime(self):
        return self.datetime

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the URL to view the liveblog.
        """
        return "/feed/%s/" % self.slug

    def body_intro(self):
        """
        Short first part of the body to show in the admin or other compressed
        views to give you some idea of what this is.
        """
        return self.body[:50]

    def html_body(self):
        """
        Returns the rendered HTML body to show to browsers.
        You could change this method to instead render using RST/Markdown,
        or make it pass through HTML directly (but marked safe).
        """
        return linebreaks_filter(self.body)

    def send_notification(self):
        """
        Sends a notification to everyone in our Liveblog's group with our
        content.
        """
        # Make the payload of the notification. We'll JSONify this, so it has
        # to be simple types, which is why we handle the datetime here.
        notification = {
            "id": self.id,
            "html": self.html_body(),
            "date_created": self.date_created.strftime("%a %d %b %Y %H:%M"),
        }
        # Encode and send that message to the whole channels Group for our
        # feed. Note how you can send to a channel or Group from any part
        # of Django, not just inside a consumer.
        Group(self.feed.group_name).send({
            # WebSocket text frame, with JSON content
            "text": json.dumps(notification),
        })

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Hooking send_notification into the save of the object as I'm not
        the biggest fan of signals.
        """
        result = super(Postmie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.send_notification()
        return result
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The Foreign key creates a field called email_id". Can you show us the model of Postmie? Can you use a user as a foriegn key?

Comment: I have added the `Postmie` model. The foreign key I have created is called `email`. But the column created in the database is called `email_id`. And same with the `feed` field, the column name in the database is called `field_id`. I think this is Django's way of doing stuff.

Comment: Here, the issue is `email_id` is the `id` of the foreignkey `email` object. You could create a `post_save` signal which would create the email object, and associate this object with it.

Comment: Yes it is the id of the parent table, however I used `to_field` to change it to the actual email. Thanks @karthikr I will try what you say with the `post_save`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Usermie is your user model. This means that you have AUTH_USER_MODEL='yourapp.Usermie' in settings.py

**If you are not using *to_field*, You can do,**

I think you need to do the following

```
Postmie.objects.create(feed=feed, body=post email=request.user)
```

Or you can do

```
Postmie.objects.create(feed=feed, body=post email_id=request.user.id)
```

You should know that every foreign key is usually represented on the database with the name of the field appended with _id. This is how Django put the foreign key. Usually you should use the ORM of Django directly.

**If you are using *to_field*:Only in Django > 1.10**

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field), email should be unique.

If to_field is changed after Postmie is created. Please make sure that all values in the column have the new corresponding value.

Comment: This does not work. I think it is because `request.user.id` does not bring back a string or it is something that does not give a value that is storable or can be represented in the database in this "context". A suitable "context" would be like in my navbar where I have `request.user.username`, and it gives you the username as a string in the html page, but within Django's functions it is interpreted as something else. That is what I get from it at least. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Come to think of it, `request.user.id` or `request.user.something` should be a string in all context.

Comment: I think you are missing AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.Usermie' in your settings.py. This should use your model as AUTH_USER and attach it to request.user. In all cases id or pk are always integers. If you have in Usermie model a one to one field to User. You can user request.user.usermie as reverse relation.

Comment: I actually have my `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'usermie.Usermie'` in my `settings.py` and everything is registered `admin.py`. I can do this on the html page `{{ request.user.email}}` and get it rendered as a string on the html page. But for some reason it does not work putting it into the database.

Comment: Why you are using to_field? can you check what if you used "email=request.user.email" instead. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field

Comment: I use `to_field="email"` because I did not want the `id` in the `Postmie` table I wanted the actual user email. Well  `email_id=request.user.email` is what I was always using, and `email=request.user.email` does not work either.

Comment: as long as that email field is unique, it should work. If you have added to_field after creating Postmie. You need to update this column again with emails if there are ids in that column already. max_length also should be the same as email field in Usermie. As long as you can render request.user.email in template. You should be able to access it from this function.

Comment: That is what I am saying, going to look over my code and see what is the problem. Yes and email set to unique, and the models have been updated. Thanks for your help!